# Square free sequence

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How can we prove that $1\underbrace{99\ldots9}_{2n+1 \ \text{times}}$ has only divisors with the last digit $1$ or $9$.

Is it true that $1\underbrace{99\ldots9}_{n \ \text{times}}$ is square free, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$?

It seems to be true. I verified it for $n\leq 20$.

Comment: I can't imagine second question to be true. Consider the iteration obtained by

$x_{1,p}= 19$ (mod $p^2$)
and $x_{i+1,p}= 10x_{i,p}+9$ mod $p^2$.

Somehow for all $p$ ${x_{i,p}}$ shouldn't contain a single $0$ which is hard to believe. (In fact I think for all prime $>5$ this statement should be false?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As to the first question:

Note that your numbers can be written as $$10^{2n+1}+10^{2n+1}-1=2\times 10^{2n+1}-1=20\times 10^{2n}-1$$

Suppose $p$ is a prime which divides one of these.  We see that $20$ is a square mod($p$) from which it follows that $5$ is a square mod($p$) which implies that $p\equiv \pm 1\pmod 5$.   Your first claim follows immediately.

Second question is False: $$7^3\;|\;\left(2\times 10^{40}-1\right)$$